# Compute the operator norm of a linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a question in functional analysis for computing an operator norm:

> Compute the operator norm of the linear functional $F$ defined on $C[-1,1]$ by:
> $$
> F(u) = \int_{0}^{1} u(x) dx - \int_{-1}^{0} u(x) dx 
> $$

I am using the definition of $||.||_{\infty}$:

$$
||F|| = \sup_{ ||u|| = 1} \{ ||Fu||  \}
$$

I found that the upper bound is $2$ by noticing $||u||_{\infty} = 1$ for $u \in C[-1,1]$ and some basic inequalities. How can I find the lower bound for this linear operator?

Comment: You'll want to come up with a function $u$ that gives you $F(u)=2$. Then you know that the $\sup$ has to be at least 2. Actually the function I came up with was not continuous, so there's a little bit more to *approach* the answer

Comment: I see. So I think a function $u(x) = |x|$ would work for this which is defined on $C[-1,1]$.

Comment: I think you get 0 from $|x|$ no? Area under one side minus area under another side?

Comment: I think  I can define a sequence like this one: $u_n  = 1$ if $1/n \leq x \leq 1$ and $u_n = -1$ if $-1 \leq x \leq -1/n$.

Comment: Inside will be: $\int_{0}^{1/n} 1 dx + \int_{1/n}^{1} 1 dx  - (   \int_{-1}^{-1/n} -1 dx + \int_{-1/n}^{0} -1 dx) = 2$

Answer (score 1):

If one defines $\operatorname{sat} x= \min(1, \max(-1,x))$, then note that
with $u_n(x) =\operatorname{sat} (nx)$ we have
$F(u_n) \to 2$. Since $|F(u)| \le 2\|u\|_\infty$ we see that $\|F\| = 2$.

Note that it is not hard to show that if $\|u\|_\infty \le 1$ and
$F(u) = 2$ then we must have $u(x) = -1$ for ae. $x \in [-1,0]$ and
$u(x) = 1$ for ae. $x \in [0,1]$.

In particular, if $u$ is continuous and $\|u\|_\infty \le 1$ then
$|F(u)| < 2$.

Comment: what is ``sat(nx)`` i.e $u_n(x) = sat(nx)$?

Comment: The first sentence defines $\operatorname{sat} $.

Comment: Ok I see it thank you. I also find that you can define a sequence $u_n$ I just comment above. It also works!!!