# Find the operator norm of the following linear functional.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, problem-solving

Let $C[-1,1]$ be the normed linear space of all the continuous functions from $[-1,1]$ to $\mathbb F=\mathbb{R\text{ or }C}$,with the sup-norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$  and define $T:C[-1,1]\to \mathbb F$ to be, $T(f)=\int_{-1}^0 f(t)dt-\int_0^1 f(t)dt$.I have to show that this is a bounded linear functional and find its operator norm.I have succeeded in showing that it is a bounded functional as, $|T(f)|=\int_{-1}^1 |f(t)|dt\leq \|f\|_\infty(1+1)=2\|f\|_\infty$.Now I think that the operator norm should be $2$.In order to show that,I have to exhibit a continuous function $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb F$ such that $|T(f)|=2\|f\|_\infty$.But I am not able to find such a function.I tried to do it graphically but I think it is not easy to construct such a continuous function.I also saw a similar problem at [Compute the operator norm of a linear functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871730/compute-the-operator-norm-of-a-linear-functional). But could not understand what they are trying to do.Can someone help me?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand in that link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try to approximate the (discontinuous) function
$$f(t) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } t < 0,\\ -1 & \text{if } t \geq 0 \end{cases}$$
by continuous functions.

Comment: But the limit will not be in $C[-1,1]$.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar That's fine, though. If for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you can find $f_n \in C[-1,1]$ such that $\|Tf_n\| \geq 2 - \frac{1}{n}$, then you are done. And such functions $f_n$ you can easily find by approximating this $f$.

Comment: got it..............